# Hg Workbench Preferences are messing with me

Tags: mercurial, tortoisesvn, preferences, workbench

I use the GUI version of Hg, and in the Workbench Preferences, I wanted to add some options.

I tried to add colors for branches by branch name, which worked well. But I did a mistake when I wrote one and... I can't make my mistake disappear.

I tried to reload the Workbench, to close all Hg processes, to edit the .ini files... nothing worked.

Each time I write something in the dropdown list of the UI it saves it and I can't clear it. Now it looks weird like that:

[image: Dropdown list]

and the coloring in the Workbench doesn't work any more.

The `.ini` files look pretty well:

```
[tortoisehg]
branchcolors = default:#8080FF
branchcolors = wip_morph:#D0A030
branchcolors = wip_djobi:#30A0A0
branchcolors = wip_legulysse:#FF0000
```

I didn't find a way to clean it. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to have **one key** `branchcolors` with any amount of branches in list

> Space separated list of branch names and colors of the form branch:#XXXXXX

Just edit mercurial.ini be hand and remove duplicates

Comment: Oooooookay ! Indeed, It works. But all my previous options were still there. Is there a way to throw them away?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\TortoiseHg\TortoiseHgQt.ini` edit or delete `tortoisehg.branchcolors` from the `[settings]` section to modify or remove the history from that edit control.

In `%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini`, the current settings should be one line to be effective:

```
[tortoisehg]
branchcolors = default:#8080FF wip_morph:#D0A030 wip_djobi:#30A0A0 wip_legulysse:#FF0000
```